# Current element reference inside onclick event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a structure like below

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="CheckSiteAvailabilty('http://aajtak.intoday.in/','Aaj Tak')">
      <a class="btn-App1" href="#">
          <img src="../images/ImgVer6/Aaj Tak.png" />
      </a>
      <a class="btn-App2 " href="#">
    <div>
         Aaj Tak
    </div>
    </a>
  </li>
 ...................
</ul>
```

and created javascript function as below and trying to get the current element but not getting

```
function CheckSiteAvailabilty(website, message) {
  //$(this) change the current element ie li css
}
```

Comment: Use jquery facilities to listen events: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @zerkms I know but I want to pass two parameter in the click event. In that case I don't think I can pass the parameters. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @शेखर: pass them through `data-` attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert the flow - set the data in a declarative way as the element attribute:

```
<ul>
    <li data-url="http://aajtak.intoday.in/" data-name="Aaj Tak">
      <a class="btn-App1" href="#">
          <img src="../images/ImgVer6/Aaj Tak.png" />
      </a>
      <a class="btn-App2 " href="#">
    <div>
         Aaj Tak
    </div>
    </a>
  </li>
 ...................
</ul>
```

Then with the help of jquery you can handle it in a much nicer way than you currently have:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    var url = $this.data('url'),
        name = $this.data('name');
});
```

PS: you would use the class selector instead of `li` in case if you have multiple lists on the page.

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer.

Comment: One more query weather this `data-url` and `data-name` has any browser compatibility issues? Will it work on browser like `ie6`?

Comment: @शेखर those are just element attributes - you don't need any special support for them*, it's jquery that does all the job.

Answer (score 1):

pass `this` as a parameter to function

```
 <li onclick="CheckSiteAvailabilty(this,'http://aajtak.intoday.in/','Aaj Tak')">
```

javascript

```
 function CheckSiteAvailabilty( obj, website, message) {
  console.log(obj)
}
```

OR using jquery.

> you need to use selector as per your HTML

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul li').on('click',function(){
    console.log($(this));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass this as function parameter

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="CheckSiteAvailabilty('http://aajtak.intoday.in/','Aaj Tak', this)">
      <a class="btn-App1" href="#">
          <img src="../images/ImgVer6/Aaj Tak.png" />
      </a>
      <a class="btn-App2 " href="#">
    <div>
         Aaj Tak
    </div>
    </a>
  </li>
 ...................
</ul>

function CheckSiteAvailabilty(website, message, element) {
  alert(element);
  //$(this) change the current element ie li css
}
```

Comment: No the li doesn't have any ID.

Comment: So `this.id` will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, HTML:

```
<body>

<ul>
    <li>
      <a class="btn-App1" href="#">
          <img src="../images/ImgVer6/Aaj Tak.png" />
      </a>
      <a class="btn-App2 " href="#">
    <div>
         Aaj Tak
    </div>
    </a>
  </li>
 ...................
</ul>

</body>
```

Script will look like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click({url:"http://aajtak.intoday.in/", name: "Aaj Tak"}, CheckSiteAvailabilty);
});

function CheckSiteAvailabilty(event){ 
   alert(event.data.url);
   alert(event.data.name);
}

</script>
```

Here the data is passed through the event.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j5ougwoq/1/

instead of writing click as on `<li onclick="CheckSiteAvailabilty` give li element some class say `class="checkIt"` and add the script as below, pass `this` as a function parameter

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkIt').click( function() {
        CheckSiteAvailabilty('http://aajtak.intoday.in/','Aaj Tak', this)
    });

    function CheckSiteAvailabilty(website, message, div) {
  //$(this) change the current element ie li css
        alert(website);
        alert(message);
        $(div).addClass('red'); // or whichever class you add for css

}
});
```